# The limit of an expected value vs expected value of a limit in this betting game

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, limsup-and-liminf

**Setting**

The outcome $X$ of a slot machine takes values 1,2,or 3 with probability $p(1) = \frac{1}{2}$, $p(2) = \frac{1}{4}$, $p(3) = \frac{1}{4}$. We are given 3 for one odds, that is if we bet 1 dollar and win then we will win $3.

The betting strategy is as follows: we bet $\frac{1}{2}$ of current wealth that $X = 1$, $\frac{1}{4}$ of wealth that $X = 2$, and $\frac{1}{4}$ of wealth that $X = 3$.
So our winning after n rounds is
$$V_n = 3 V_{n-1} p(X_n).$$

Now find $\lim_n V_{n}$.

**Attempted Solution**

So I take the expected value of $V_n$ for all n and then take the expected value to the limit:

$$E[V_n] = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}\left(\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} = \left(\frac{9}{8}\right)^n$$

And $\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)^n \rightarrow^n \infty$.

**Confusion**

However, the counter argument to the solution is that we have taken then limit of an expectation, when in fact, I need to the expectation of the limit. And by Fatou's lemma

$$\lim inf E[V_n] \ge E[\lim inf V_n]$$

So I found an upper bound that diverges and therefore cannot conclude anything about $V_n$. Please explain the subtleties here?

**Alternate Solution**

Now consider this alternate solution and please explain why it makes sense relative to Fatou's lemma. Define $\log := \log_2$. And note

$$V_n = 3^n V_o  P(X_1) \cdot \ldots \cdot P(X_n)$$

So let $V_o = 1$ and we have:

$$2^{\log V_n} = 2^{n \log 3 + \log V_o + \log P(X_1) + \ldots + \log P(X_n)}$$

And by LLN $\log P(X_1) + \ldots + \log P(X_n) \rightarrow^n n E[\log(X_j)] = n \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1}{4} \right)$.

And the rest is just algebra.

But my primary concern is how does taking a limiting argument for the sum of $P(X_j)$'s sit wrt Fatou's lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected values can be misleading.  We have

$$ \mathbb E[V_{n+1}|V_{n}] = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{3}{2} V_n + \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{3}{4} V_n = \dfrac{9}{8} V_n $$
so that $\mathbb E[V_n] = (9/8)^n V_0 \to \infty$.

However, the Strong Law of Large Numbers is about sums, not products.
To make a product into a sum, we take logarithms.

$$ V_n = V_0 \prod_{j=1}^n X_j \ \text{so} \log V_n = \log V_0 + \sum_{j=1}^n \log X_j $$
with
$$\mathbb E[\log X_j] = \dfrac{1}{2} \log (3/2) + \dfrac{1}{2} \log(3/4) = \dfrac{1}{2} \log(9/8)$$

This is still positive, so it's still a good bet, but not quite as good
as what the expected value would lead you to think.  What the Strong Law
says is that almost surely, $$\dfrac{1}{n} \log V_n \to \dfrac{1}{2} \log(9/8)
\ \text{as}\ n \to \infty$$
So for any $\epsilon \in (0,9/8)$, with probability $1$ we can say that for large enough $n$, $(9/8- \epsilon)^{n/2} V_0 < V_n < (9/8 + \epsilon)^{n/2} V_0$.  In particular, $\lim_{n \to \infty} V_n = +\infty$.  But notice that
this almost-sure growth of $V_n$ is much slower than the growth of the expected value.

For an example where the expected value grows but the investment almost surely goes to $0$, see this [Maple application](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=127116) that I wrote a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Each round, you have $1/2$ chance of multiplying your money  by $3/2$ and $1/2$ chance of multiplying it by $3/4$.  You are correct that the expectation after one round is $9/8$. For any finite number of rounds, your expectation is then $(9/8)^n$.  After $n$ rounds you have a distribution of results.  If you have won $m$ times, you have $\frac {3^n}{2^n \cdot 2^{n-m}}$. For finite $n$ you can calculate the expected value over this distribution.  The distriution does not have a limit as $n \to \infty,$ so you can't calculate its expectation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? Specifically, what would the expected value of the limit be?

Comment: As you said, the limit of the expected value is $+\infty$ or doesn't exist if you don't accept that as a limit.  The problem is that the limit of the probability distribution does not exist, so you can't take its expected value.  Informally, when we calculate the expected value of the limit, we have $0 \cdot \infty + 1 \cdot 0$. where the first term in the product is the probability and the second is the value.  The undefined term spoils everything.